# How to fix "Shell Script Invocation Error" in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, shell

I keep trying to run my Xcode project (named "ppsideloader") and it keeps giving me 2 errors. Also I Cleaned and Built many times then tried to run, but still same problem.

First Error:

> /Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ppsideloader-flikuhbwvklweghesxwygrfiylum/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ppsideloader.app/*.dylib: No such file or directory

Second Error:

> Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

My Build Phases:
[image]

I don't know what to do, I tried almost everything. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Do you have any run scripts set in your project build phases?

Comment: Can you show your scrpt file ? /Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ppsideloader-flikuhbwvklweghesxwygrfiylum/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ppsideloader.app is wrong. .app is not a directory. Try removing to give the exact directory/folder name to the path.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri When I try to open file it said "You can’t open the application “ppsideloader” because it is not supported on this type of Mac." It's weird till few days ago this project worked now it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

@Emm...I also faced Same Issue. But the issue is fixed when i re install xcode and restarted my machine.

Try the Same i hope that it will be helpfull to you